# VirtualBox Portable will not start

Tags: portable-apps, virtualbox

I downloaded and extracted the contents of VirtualBox Portable from  [vbox.me](http://www.vbox.me/) but I get the error below when launching portable VirtualBox. What can I do to fix this error?

[image: VBox Error]

I have .Net framework 2.0 and 3.5 installed. 
Whenever I try to install 3.5 I get this error:

[image: .Net Error]

Comment: Is your user in the PC's local Administrator's group? I installed Portable VB specifically because we don't have Admin access to our machines, but it would appear that Admin rights are still required to do the initial DLL registration. Without it, it fails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of .Net does the computer you're trying to run this on have installed? If possible, I would installed the latest versions

Basically, what this error is telling you is that the program requested a class from the registry, which makes me think there's something that is not installed on the computer that's required to run Virtual Box Portable.

Did you ever get to the "Portable-VirtualBox *** Extract and/or Compress ***" window?

#### Edit:

Okay, next thought - it looks like you're running Windows 7. Do you have UAC disabled? VirtualBox is probably trying to register a COM object with the OS, and without administrative permissions, it won't be able to. I would try running the portable exe as an administrator (right-click -> Run as administrator) or, if it's disabled, enabling UAC and see if that helps.

Comment: yup,I already got d portable virtual box folder

Comment: @Nrew updated my answer with a new thought.

Comment: yeah you are right, Ive disabled the uac because its really annoying.Thanks it works now

Answer (score 1):

jus turn on the windows feature jus 
goto control panel > Add remove program > turn windows features shown on left > tick the .net3.5 checkbox then ok u r done

Comment: its enabled but still wont work, see the screenshots